# service reference proxy class renamed

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight, svc

I'm having my Web Application which hosts Webservices (svc) which are used in a Silverlight Webapplication. After a while I added some new stuff to my Service and now I tried to refresh my proxy classes in the Silverlight Application Project.

Unfortunately, Visual Studio now generates new class names.
Before I had this:

```
public SilverlightApplication.ServiceReferenceDoc.Document Document
```

but now I get a different class name (number one behind the name)

```
SilverlightApplication.ServiceReferenceDoc.Document1 Document
```

Which is really bad because my Silverlight Projects have a lot webservices and these have a lot of code which uses these proxy classes.

So far I found out it generates the proxy class 2 times.

Some ideas why this renaming is happening? I already tried VS2015, VS2013 and also I deleted the complete reference and add it again, but it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had mixed EF classes with own classes. That caused the generation of two classes with the same name.